# How to check for equality when yielding parts of an iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, yield

I am passing an iterator to a function, and comparing previous/current/next items in the iterator.

The MRE below shows that I cannot check whether `previous_item` is equal to `current_item`, when the last two elements are the same.

```
def test(current):

    iterator = iter(current)
    previous_item = None
    current_item = next(iterator)
    flag = 'none'
    
    for next_item in iterator:
        
        if previous_item == current_item:
            flag = 'here'
            yield previous_item, current_item, next_item, flag

        else:
            flag = 'none'
            yield previous_item, current_item, next_item, flag

        previous_item = current_item
        current_item = next_item
        

    yield (previous_item, current_item, None, flag)
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]
    for prev, curr, nex, flag in test(l): 
        print(prev, curr, nex, flag)
```

Actual output:

```
None 0 1 none
0 1 2 none
1 2 3 none
2 3 3 none
3 3 None none
```

Expected output:

```
None 0 1 none
0 1 2 none
1 2 3 none
2 3 3 none
3 3 None here
```

How can I evaluate the logic of this program for the last two elements, such that I get my expected results?

Regards,

Comment: This isn't necessarily your problem here, but I don' think you want `previous_item is current_item`. You want `previous_item == current_item` instead. For small numbers it should work fine, but you'll get weird behavior with almost anything else.

Comment: The actual data are strings.`==` gives me the same result.

Comment: That's still iffy. Only use `is` when you want to check for one object being *the same literal object* as something else. `is` doesn't do value comparisons.

Comment: And also, if you put `print(">>", previous_item, current_item)` right above the check, you'll see that they're never equal. There's a bug in your logic elsewhere unrelated to the check.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I read that `is` is generally faster. But yes, I know you are right about this. Yes, this post is more about a bug in the logic.

Comment: I believe the logic error is that `next_item` is never used until the *next* iteration of the loop; after it's been assigned to `current_item`. The problem is, on the last iteration, there is no next iteration, so the last `3` is never used.

Comment: Seems that using `l = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]` doesn't work either, unless I use an else clause.

Comment: With two leading `0`s, I get `here` multiple times.

Comment: Right, I updated the code in this post to account for this. Thanks! Your comment on the next never actually being used in the next iteration is it. I just don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test(current):
    iterator = iter(current)
    previous_item = None
    current_item = next(iterator)
    flag = 'none'
    next_item = True
    
    while next_item:
        try:
            next_item = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            next_item = None

        if previous_item == current_item:
            flag = 'here'
            yield previous_item, current_item, next_item, flag
        else:
            flag = 'none'
            yield previous_item, current_item, next_item, flag

        previous_item = current_item
        current_item = next_item
    
    if current_item:
        yield (previous_item, current_item, next_item, flag)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3]
    for prev, curr, nex, flag in test(l): 
        print(prev, curr, nex, flag)
```

Output

```
None 0 1 none
0 1 2 none
1 2 3 none
2 3 3 none
3 3 None here
```